smooth transition from one color to another color for QT
I've created a moving line animation in Qt and store the colors in a vector. The initial value of this vector is red. As the user slides a button in the UI, new colors are added to the vector, and the line color changes as the user changes the color. There is a certain offset distance between the lines. When transitioning from one color to another, I want a smooth transition, meaning if it's transitioning from green to red, it shouldn't be abrupt. How can I achieve this?
Animation Code:
void SmoothLinesAnimationThread::SmoothLineAnimationDraws(cv::Mat& img)
{
img= cv::Mat(280,390, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
img.setTo(cv::Scalar(core->StaticSmoothSet.background_color.blue(), core->StaticSmoothSet.background_color.green(), core->StaticSmoothSet.background_color.red()));
Core::SmoothDynamicSettings lines;

if(core->StaticSmoothSet.offset>=core->StaticSmoothSet.Delta){
if(core->StaticSmoothSet.currSmoothLineColorIndex>=core->StaticSmoothSet.SmoothLinesC.size()){
        core->StaticSmoothSet.currSmoothLineColorIndex=0;
}

cv::Scalar lineColor = cv::Scalar(core->StaticSmoothSet.SmoothLinesC[core->StaticSmoothSet.currSmoothLineColorIndex].red(),
core->StaticSmoothSet.SmoothLinesC[core->StaticSmoothSet.currSmoothLineColorIndex].green(),
core->StaticSmoothSet.SmoothLinesC[core->StaticSmoothSet.currSmoothLineColorIndex].blue());

core->StaticSmoothSet.currSmoothLineColorIndex++;

Core::SmoothDynamicSettings newSmoothLineLeft= {0, lineColor};
core->StaticSmoothSet.Sline.push_back(newSmoothLineLeft);
core->StaticSmoothSet.offset= 0;
}

for(const auto& line: core->StaticSmoothSet.Sline){
    int newX= line.position;
    if(core->StaticSmoothSet.inverse){
        cv::line(img, cv::Size(newX,0), cv::Size(newX, img.rows), line.currColor,core->StaticSmoothSet.lineSize);
    }
    else
    {
        cv::line(img, cv::Size(newX,0), cv::Size(newX, img.rows), cv::Scalar(line.currColor[2], line.currColor[1], line.currColor[0]),
        core->StaticSmoothSet.lineSize);
    }
}

for(auto&line: core->StaticSmoothSet.Sline){
    line.position+= static_cast<int>(5*speed);
}

core->StaticSmoothSet.Sline.erase(std::remove_if(core->StaticSmoothSet.Sline.begin(),
core->StaticSmoothSet.Sline.end(), [&](const Core::SmoothDynamicSettings& line){
return (line.position > img.cols);}), core->StaticSmoothSet.Sline.end());

core->StaticSmoothSet.offset+= static_cast<int>(5*speed);

if(core->StaticSmoothSet.offset>= core->Image.cols){
    core->StaticSmoothSet.offset=0;
}

}

Look at this Q&A.

Qt provides an animation framework, you may take a look at QVariantAnimation.
